# Вывод слайса в Голанг наоборот

Tags: golang

Я только начинаю знакомиться с голангом.
Я создал слайс с капасити 10. Заполнил его тремя значением. При выводе эти значения оказались в конце. Почему так происходит?[image: код]

[image: вывод]

Comment: 1) Мы картинки смотреть не любим 2) Что делает append?

Comment: вы создали массив не с capacity 10, а длиной 10. Если вы хотите создать массив с capacity 10 создайте слайс так `arr := make([]string, 0, 10)`

Answer (score 1):

давайте разберем вашу программу построчно

строка 12 - создает массив из строк с длиной 10 
строка 17 - добавляет к существующему массиву в конец новый элемент. 
по этой причине вы наблюдаете в логах, что ваш массив имеет размер 13

это произошло потому, что конструкция вида
`a := make([]int, 5)  // len(a)=5` создает массив уже заполненных нулями элементов `a len=5 cap=5 [0 0 0 0 0]`

в языке есть понятие `len` и `cap` (length and capacity) 
len - сколько элементов находится в массиве 
cap - какая емкость у массива

примеры,

```
a := make([]int, 5)  // a len=5 cap=5 [0 0 0 0 0]
b := make([]int, 0, 5) // len(b)=0, cap(b)=5 [] 
b = b[:cap(b)] // len(b)=5, cap(b)=5
b = b[1:]      // len(b)=4, cap(b)=4
```

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make([]int, 5)
    printSlice("a", a)

    b := make([]int, 0, 5)
    printSlice("b", b)

    c := b[:2]
    printSlice("c", c)

    d := c[2:5]
    printSlice("d", d)
}

func printSlice(s string, x []int) {
    fmt.Printf("%s len=%d cap=%d %v\n",
        s, len(x), cap(x), x)
}
```

вывод:

> a len=5 cap=5 [0 0 0 0 0] 
> b len=0 cap=5 [] 
> c len=2 cap=5 [0 0] 
> d len=3 cap=3 [0 0 0]